# Conditional values in .screenrc?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I've rearranged my work machine a bit and now keep my terminal open on a vertically-oriented monitor, which has caused me to have somewhat different needs from GNU screen. Up until this change, I've been sharing the same .screenrc file between the machine in question (a mac), and two arch-linux boxes.

Matching some of the conditionals I've put in my .bashrc to configure things for the different systems, is there any way to provide conditional behavior to, e.g., split the display into horizontal panels on one system, and vertical panels on another?

Having not seen anything in the [Screen User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), the closest thing I can think to try is setting up my .bashrc to send screen commands ala `screen -S <name> -X <command>` and let the .bashrc file figure out what to do, but that feels a bit like building a rube goldberg machine out of scripts and config files.

Comment: Is it a requirement to share one file across three systems? You could simply use separate file for that one.

Comment: Separate files is what I've ended up with, but I prefer not to duplicate code (or in this case, configurations). Why duplicate the entire file when only one aspect needs to be different for the new case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long time (13 years or so) `GNUscreen` user I am pretty sure there is no such feature in `GNUscreen`.
If you do not mind I would suggest switching to `tmux`, as it has vastly superior support to multi-panel work flows.
It is possible to configure `tmux` so it has virtually identical keyboard shortcuts as `GNUscreen` (though the default are quite different). Moreover `tmux` has `if-shell` statement that essentially does what you asked here for `GNUscreen` to support.
Although it does not answer your question in positive way, I hope this info to be helpful.

Per request adding my .tmux.conf (for version 1.9):

```
# starts here:

set-option -sg prefix C-a
set-option -sga update-environment " MRXVT_TABTITLE TERMINATOR_UUID TERMINATOR_DBUS_NAME TERM_NO TERMINATOR_DBUS_PATH REMOTEHOST REMOTE_HOST"
set-option -sga terminal-overrides ",xterm*:smul=\e[35;1m:smcup@:rmcup@:acsc=\`\`aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~+>-\^.v0#,*rxvt*:smul=\e[35;1m:smcup@:rmcup@:acsc=\`\`aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~+>-\^.v0#,vte*:sitm=\e[34;1;7m:smul=\e[35;1m:smcup@:rmcup@:acsc=\`\`aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~+>-\^.v0#"
set-environment -gr TERM_NO
unbind-key C-b
bind-key a send-prefix
set-option -sg visual-bell on
set-option -sg default-terminal screen-256color-bce
set-option -sg status off
set-option -sg default-command ${SHELL}
set-option -sg message-bg green
set-option -sg message-fg black
set-option -sg message-attr default
set-option -sg message-command-bg green
set-option -sg pane-active-border-fg red
set-option -sg pane-active-border-bg black
set-option -sg pane-border-fg red
set-option -sg pane-border-bg black
set-option -sg status-bg green
set-option -sg mode-bg green
set-option -sg display-time 500
set-option -sg mode-mouse on
set-option -sg mouse-select-pane on
set-option -sg mouse-select-window on
set-option -sg lock-command vlock
set-option -sg xterm-keys on
set-option -sg repeat-time 0
set-option -sg escape-time 10
set-window-option -g monitor-activity on

bind-key C-c new-window -c ${PWD}
bind-key C-n next-window
bind-key Space next-window
bind-key C-Space next-window
bind-key BSpace previous-window
bind-key C-BSpace previous-window
bind-key C-p previous-window
bind-key C-d detach-client
bind-key C-[ copy-mode
bind-key C-] paste-buffer
unbind-key l
unbind-key x
bind-key C-a last-window
unbind &
bind-key x lock-session
bind-key C-x lock-session
bind-key K confirm-before -p "Really kill window #W? (y/n)" kill-window
bind-key '"' choose-window
bind-key _ split-window
bind-key | split-window -h
bind-key M-1 select-pane -t 0
bind-key M-2 select-pane -t 1
bind-key M-3 select-pane -t 2
bind-key M-4 select-pane -t 3
```

Comment: I don't mind the suggestion; I've been meaning to give `tmux` a decent try, but the longer I put it off the more I've gotten used to `GNUscreen`. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, like I said in my answer, with proper `.tmux.conf` `tmux` becomes drop-in replacement for `GNUscreen`. There is no rational reason to use `GNUscreen` on platforms where `tmux` is available. I am talking from personal experience, after I set up my `.tmux.conf` the transition was super smooth. I use `tmux` for 66% of my time and I kept all habits from `GNUscreen` while I have access to supreme `pane` handling in `tmux`. I you wish I can attach my `.tmux.conf` which sole purpose is to make `tmux` `GNUscreen`'s drop-on replacement.

Comment: Actually, that'd be amazing. Spending a day reading tmux config docs seems like a lot of time I could be using to do work, like whatever I did on Friday. At least, I think I did work on Friday... I guess I'll spend Monday with tmux! :D

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Screen's [`source`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Source) command to pull in any config that needs to vary by machine, i.e. add this to `.screenrc`:

```
source $HOME/.screenrc.local
```

then add any per-machine config to `.screen.local`.